# Use of < in while loop

Tags: bash

I've seen much documentation and examples of using `while` in a bash script but none that explain what the `<` is doing in this:

```
while read p; do 
echo $p
done < $filename
```

What exactly is the program flow in the above, and how does `<` work?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redirection_(computing) OR http://sc.tamu.edu/help/general/unix/redirection.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to refer to [redirection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redirection_%28computing%29).

Saying:

```
command < filename
```

executes `command` with `filename` as the input.

The command that you mention reads one line at a time from the file denoted by `$filename`.

You might also want to refer to `help while` and `help read`.

Comment: thank you. it seems odd that the redirection in my example is happening with the command "done" -- that doesn't seem intuitive

Comment: @OpenLearner It's the `read` that is _consuming_ the redirection and the `while` is causing it to happen in a loop.

Comment: The entire `while ...; do ...; done` loop is a single *compound command* in `bash`. The input redirection applies to it; the `read` command inherits its standard input from the `while` loop that contains it, which allows you to consume a different line of input each time `read` is called in the loop.